# Automapper for Java

Tags: java, .net, mapping, automapper

Is there Java equivalent of .Net's [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: If you could tell us what Automapper does in .NET, then we Java-freaks could answer as well ;-)

Comment: @Joachim Sauer http://automapper.codeplex.com

Comment: Despite this question being closed, it contains a lot of great information! There are many other mappers not mentioned here. Please see this article for a great comparison of examples and performance (2018): https://www.baeldung.com/java-performance-mapping-frameworks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Checkout the [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) project.

Dozer supports simple property mapping, complex type mapping, bi-directional mapping, implicit-explicit mapping, as well as recursive mapping.

It makes use of [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) and extends on it.

Comment: Future readers, keep in mind that Dozer is one of the slowest mappers available. This may or may not matter for you depending on your usage :)

Answer (score 23):

Check out my [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org). It was inspired by AutoMapper, but adds a few new things such as intelligent mapping.

> ModelMapper is an intelligent object
> mapping framework that eliminates the
> need to manually map objects to each
> other. It uses a convention-based
> approach to map objects while
> providing a simple refactoring safe
> API for handling specific mapping
> scenarios.

http://modelmapper.org

Also a brief blog post from Jimmy Bogard, the creator of AutoMapper:

http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/09/17/automapper-for-java/

Comment: Be aware of this issue if writting custom mappings:
https://github.com/jhalterman/modelmapper/issues/87

I just ran in to this one at it's thrown a bit of a spanner in the works!

Comment: ModelMapper appears really powerful. As someone coming from C#/AutoMapper background, I would recommend checking this out.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the open source project [Beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/).