# Polymorphism and DTO object creation

Tags: java, dto

I develop application which contains few tiers. We have DAO layer which returns model objects. We also have mappers which instantiate DTO objects and send them to clients. Entities are mapped to DTOs in Controller layer. I've introduced inheritance in few entity classes. Let's assume sth like on image below

[class diagram (not enough reputation points to past image directly)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5XHo.jpg)

I ask DAO for list of animals from the concrete ZOO. Then I get list List animals, but they are of concrete type because Animal is abstract and we cannot have just Animal in the database. I would like to create DTOs from this model objects. I have to use mapper in which I have if .. else statements checking type of each animal and then creating proper DTO, sth like

```
if (animal instanceof Dog) {
  .. create dog dto
} else if (animal instance of Cat) {
  .. create cat dto
} .. and so on
```

This code does not look nice. It would be nice to use polymorphism and call some method on each animal to produce DTO, but it is bad to have logic in domain model creating DTO objects just to communication. How do you resolve such situations?

Edit:
To be more specific, I want to have DTO like
1. DogDTO which contains only fields color and name
2. FishDTO which contains only numberOfFins
Not one big AnimalDTO with all possible attributes

Answer (score 7):

You want to select a different transformation for a different type of object. Basically there are two approaches to this problem in Java:

1. Use the `instanceof` or map the Class of the object to a specialized Transformer object by getting it from a repository (could be simple Map<Class, Transfomer>). This is the approach that the frameworks suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3319002/116148) use.
2. Use the visitor pattern. The idea of this approach is that the simplest approach would be to have a `toDTO()` method in all of your domain objects, but this would introduce an unwanted dependency in your domain objects on your DTO's. Another approach would be to have all these classes in a single object `toDTO(Dog d)` `toDTO(Fish f)`, but unfortunately the single-dispatch feature in Java means that to be able to use this, you would still have to figure out the type of the object you want to transform and call the right method: the VM cannot do this for you. The Visitor pattern is a design pattern that solves this problem.

The basic design of the visitor pattern is like this:

```
public abstract class AnimalVisitor<T> {

  public abstract T visit (Dog d);

  public abstract T visit (Fish f);

  ...

}

public abstract class Animal {

  public <T> abstract T accept (AnimalVisitor<T> v);

  ...

}

public class Dog extends Animal {

  public <T> T accept (AnimalVisitor<T> v) {
    return v.visit(this);
  }

  ...

}

public class Fish extends Animal {

  public <T> T accept (AnimalVisitor<T> v) {
    return v.visit(this);
  }

  ...

}

public class DTOTransformer extends AnimalVisitor<DTO> {

  public DogDTO visit (Dog d) {
    return new DogDTO(d);
  }

  public FishDTO visit (Fish f) {
    return new FishDTO(f);
  }

}
```

When you introduce a new Animal type, you need to add a new `visit` method to the `AnimalVisitor` class. You will be prompted to do this, since you will have to implement the `accept` method in the new Animal type. This will also prompt you to update the `DTOTransformer` and any other implementations of the `AnimalVisitor`.

As you can see, this approach requires a lot more code then the simple `instanceof` style approach. It does provide you with a nice extendable mechanisme for other similar operations you would want to do on your domain.

I guess it really depends on your situation which approach is best. I would, however, always recommend using a framework like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) or [ModdelMapper](http://modelmapper.org) over writing the `if (.. instanceof ...) else if (...` myself.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I considered second option but as you wrote it couples model layer with communication layer what is even worse than using instanceof in my opinion. With map of transformers I also need to populate it with data (add keys/classes and proper mappers). But maybe it will look better and will be more reusable. I will think about it.

Comment: @user3201879 Using the visitor pattern will decouple the layers nicely.

Comment: Yes, that is much more code but coder will not forget about implementing proper methods, you are right. I will consider Visitor pattern. Dozer and ModdelMapper would be another mini-tier in application which could make some another problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you really have a domain model - do they actual have domain logic, or are they just data containers?

Anyway, this mapping logic should be in the outer layer where the DTO's are exposed, not in the domain layer. The whole idea is to make domain not dependent on an outer layer.

Just create mappers (for example as extension methods) in your controller layer that can be reused. Example:

```
public class AnimalDto
{
    public string Sound { get; set; }
}

public class CatDto : AnimalDto
{

}

public class DogDto : AnimalDto
{
    public bool IsTrained {get; set;}
}

public class AnimalDo
{
    public string Sound { get; set; }
}

public class CatDo : AnimalDo
{        
}

public class DogDo : AnimalDo
{
    public bool IsTrained {get; set;}
}

public static class MappingExtensions
{
    public static AnimalDto Map(this AnimalDo animalDo)
    {
        if (animalDo is CatDo) return (animalDo as CatDo).Map();
        if (animalDo is DogDo) return (animalDo as DogDo).Map();
        return null;
    }

    public static DogDto Map(this DogDo dogDo)
    {
        return new DogDto() { IsTrained = dogDo.IsTrained, Sound = dogDo.Sound };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
AnimalDo animal = new DogDo() { IsTrained = true, Sound = "bwarf"};
var dogDto = animal.Map();
```

Or optionally use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.codeplex.com/) to do the mappings for you.

**EDIT:** noticed that you just added JAVA tag, while my code was a C# example. In java it seems you don't have extensions methods, but you can write normal static classes also. See [here](https://automapper.codeplex.com/). And it seems there's also something like [automapper for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319002/automapper-for-java).

Comment: They are rather containers. Do you recommend to stay with 'instanceof' logic and create proper DTO by type?

Comment: Personally I don't think there's anything wrong with that. I added an example.

Comment: Currently I have almost same solution as you have posted. But I wanted to do it in better way to not remeber about adding new instanceof case and type checking when adding new Animal type and new DTO type. I thought about it for a while and creating some kind of factory and using instanceof seems to be the best way. Perfectly would be to iterate over list of animals and call some interface/abstract method to create proper DTO.

Comment: Rather strategy is important here than concrete language :) In OOP instanceof is rather a bad practice that's the motivation why I'm asking about that.

Answer (score 0):

With `instanceof` you can't use proxies for the objects you're working with. That can be a problem when you use ORM solutions like Hibernate, because you would always need to read the full state of the instance from DB just to be sure that you can check its type in use cases when you need to.

One of the alternatives would be to declare `getType()` method and override it in each subclass:

```
abstract class Animal {
   abstract AnimalType getType();
}

class Dog extends Animal {
   @Override
   AnimalType getType() {
      return AnimalType.DOG;
   }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
   @Override
   AnimalType getType() {
      return AnimalType.CAT;
   }
}
```

This way you get rid of the `instanceof` operator (meaning you get more OOP flexibility in general, for example to use proxies, decorators, etc).

Since `AnimalType` will probably be an `enum`, then you also get the ability to use it in `switch` statements in your DTO factories and similar places, which is a little bit more readable than `if...else if` with `instanceof`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my inheritance structure I use discriminator which is almost same as the getType. I can map column to the attribute without overriding method getType in each class. But still I need to check the type somewhere and create proper DTO ;)